# search and heighlight row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Search in asp and highlight result in grid view row asp

how can i do that???????????

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="600px" 
                          AllowPaging="True" PageSize="8"
                          CssClass="Grid"                     
                          AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                          PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  >         
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                      <Columns>
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" SortExpression="Time" />
                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                      </Columns>

    <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr"></PagerStyle>
            </asp:GridView
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If grid doesn't filter the rows, you can add a css class in `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    if(/*row matches search pattern*/)
    {
        row.CssClass = "HighlightedRow";
    }
}
```